# Distinguish between single select and multiselect event in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have the following event handling logic in Fabric.js. I am trying to distinguish between the selection of a single object, and the selection of multiple objects (multiselect). How can I do this?

Code:

```
canvas.on({
    'selection:created': handleSelection,
    'selection:updated': handleSelection,
    'selection:cleared': handleSelection,
});

function handleSelection(obj) {
    if (obj.isMultiSelect()) {  // <- ATTENTION. How do I implement this?
        // Do something.
    } else if (obj.isSingleSelect()) {  // <- ATTENTION. How do I implement this?
        // Do another thing.
    }
}
```

I have implemented `if (obj.isMultiSelect())` using `if (obj.updated && obj.deselected.length == 0)`, but it looks like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with  getActiveObjects() method

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

function addCheckbox(left,top, width,height){
    var imgClass = new fabric.Image.fromURL('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33281.svg',
    function(img){        
        img.width = width; 
        img.height = height;
        img.left = left; 
        img.top = top;     
        
        img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        if(e.target.opacity <= 0.5){
            e.target.opacity = 1;
        }else{
            e.target.opacity = 0.4;
        }
        canvas.renderAll();    
        });
        canvas.add(img);
        canvas.renderAll();        
        })    
    }

addCheckbox(0,0,100,100)
addCheckbox(100,100,100,100)

function isMultipleSelected(){

  if(canvas.getActiveObjects().length>1){
  return true; 
  }
  return false;
}

function isSingleSelected(){
 if(canvas.getActiveObjects().length== 1){
    return true
  }
  return false 
}

canvas.on({
    'selection:created': handleSelection,
    'selection:updated': handleSelection,
    'selection:cleared': handleSelection,
});

function handleSelection(obj) {
    if (isMultipleSelected()) {  // <- ATTENTION. How do I implement this?
        // Do something.
        console.log("Yes Multiple selected")
    } else if(isSingleSelected())  {  // <- ATTENTION. How do I implement this?
        // Do another thing.
        console.log("Yes Single selected")
    }else {
      console.log("Nothing selected")
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color:silver;
}
canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"> </script>
<button onClick="isMultipleSelected()">
    Check Selection
</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
```